# Java class loader tutorial

Tags: java, classloader

Please provide a good, thorough tutorial about **Java class loading**, focusing on how to extend that mechanism and how to actually work with the extension.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

There's obviously [Sun's trail](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/ext/basics/load.html) which gives you the technical foundations.  I find that despite being thirteen years old(!) this [JavaWorld](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-10-1996/jw-10-indepth.html) article is still a very good place to start - the technicalities of classloading haven't changed much or at all since then, to my knowledge.  (Someone please correct this if there have been any important changes since then!).

IBM are usually good for technical Java articles, and they [don't disappoint](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-dyn0429/) here. O'Reilly also have [a more recent article](http://onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2005/01/26/classloading.html) that covers much the same thing but has a pretty diagram in it. :-)

Answer (score 5):

The [Mindprod Java Glossary](http://mindprod.com/jgloss/classloader.html) has a good description of what a classloader is and lists tutorials and technical articals at the end of the page.