# How to set the class path using a java program

Tags: java

Setting a java class path not by using command prompt by using a java program.
Everywhere we have description about how to set path and class path using cmd or by going to environment variables but I want to set the class path using a java program

Answer (score 0):

You can set the classpath when invoking a Java process. AFAIK you cannot modify the classpath within a running java program. So there are two ways to deal with that:

**Invoke another JVM**

Construct the command as you would have passed it on the command line, then use [ProcessBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) to run this command. It will create another process that runs your application. Noone needs to know your application is still in memory with 'the wrong' classpath.

**Use a different Classloader**

Create a Classloader that loads classes from your desired classpath. Load the classes in question through that classloader and invoke them as needed. See also [Java class loader tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1673256/java-class-loader-tutorial)
With this solution the operating system sees only one process.

This technique is commonly used in application servers or systems with a plugin architecture. You could therefore check out e.g. [Apache Felix](https://felix.apache.org/documentation/index.html).